# I want To find the number of weeks with start date and end date of each for the month using moment.js

Tags: momentjs

```
let currentDate = moment();
let weekStart = currentDate.clone().startOf('week');
let weekEnd = currentDate.clone().endOf('week');
```

I want to know the start date and end date of every week for a given month.
expected output

```
In August month 

In Array of object
1. 1 Aug 2021 - 7 Aug 2021
2. 8 Aug 2021 - 14 Aug 2021
3. 15 Aug 2021 - 21 Aug 2021
4. 22 Aug 2021 - 28 Aug 2021
5. 29 Aug 2021 - 31 Aug 2021
```

Comment: Its a bit confusing. Could you provide sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

```
moment().startOf('week');
moment().endOf('week');
```

Refrence:
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/moment-js-get-current-week-start-and-end-date-exampleexample.html